# Permission denied to make files in Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, jenkins

I try to make file in SSH Server through Jenkins.
(Jenkins build environment is 'Send files or execute commands over SSH after the build runs.')

I made shell script for making postgresql database backup files through the command 'pg_dump' at particular directory and it was works when I executed the script in Linux.

But, when I executed Jenkins job, It didn't working and gave me the error message like 'a.txt : permission denied'

I already gave all permission(rwx) to the account that Jenkins uses.

How Can I solve it?

Comment: You can open your terminal , then use ```~] mkdir <filename>``` command, if not sing as root user and use it again

Answer (score 0):

In Execute Shell command add this line first. This should solve your problem.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
yourcommand here
```

Comment: The comment is 
#! /bin/bash 
echo "password" | sudo su postgres -c 'pg_dump -d database -U postgres -F t > $(date +%Y-%m-%d).backup'